# ¿Cómo seleccionar todos los elementos de un mismo tipo y acceder a ellos de forma individual? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, array, selectores

Tengo 7 imagenes un mi documento. Y sé que haciendo esto se seleccionan todas ellas.

```
els = $('img');
```

¿Pero cómo hago para acceder a cada una por separado? (a ser posible como si fuera un array).

Lo que quiero hacer es conseguir el **id** de cada imagen (algo así pero que funcione).

```
els = $('img');

for(var i = 0 ; i<els.length;i++)
alert( $( 'img:eq('+ i +')' ).prop("id")  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método que estás buscando es [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

HTML de ejemplo:

```
<img id="uno" src="1.jpg" alt="Imagen Uno">
<img id="dos" src="2.jpg" alt="Imagen Dos">
<img id="tres" src="3.jpg" alt="Imagen Tres">
```

Javascript:

```
$('img').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).prop('id'))
})
```

Output en la consola:

```
uno
dos
tres
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @DavidSilva es perfecto!!!

Comment: De nada, me alegro de que te sirva!